# It is possible combining two linq queries into one?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I have a table (User) in my database that looks like this (table structure with example data):

[image]

Each user has a unique IdUser, while several users can have the same IdLicense. I want to select in one query list of all users with this same IdLicense using only IdUser. I do this using two linq query:

```
 //Get logged user IdUser
 var claims = User.Identities.FirstOrDefault()?.Claims.FirstOrDefault()?.Value;

 //Get logged user IdLicense
 var license = _context.User.Where(x => x.IdUser == new Guid(claims))
               .Select(x => x.IdLicense).FirstOrDefault();

 //Get users with this license
 var users = _context.User.Where(x => x.IdLicense == license).ToList();
```

It is possible get this same list of users with this license using only one linq query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one should work fast:

```cs
var userId = new Guid(claims);

var query = 
   from ul in _context.Users
   where ul.IdUser == userId
   join u in _context.Users on ul.IdLicense equals u.IdLicense
   select u;

var users = query.ToList();
```

Comment: I checked, your code in five tries is average in 65ms, Mohsen Esmailpour code in 75.6ms on average. Thanks a lot for your suggestion :) My code from question reach avarage 158ms

Comment: Nothing special, other answer introduces OUTER APPLY, which is not so fast operation and not needed in this case.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be this:

```
var userId = new Guid(claims);
var users = (from user in _context.Users
            let licenseId = _context.User.Where(x => x.IdUser == userId)
               .Select(x => x.IdLicense).FirstOrDefault();
            where user.IdLicense == licenseId).ToList();
```

Comment: I've slightly tweaked your code (no Select at the end of the query) and it works perfect. Thank you